# Using acts_as_list, set scope to string column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-list

Using [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list), I'm trying to set the scope to the `where` column.

```
acts_as_list scope: :where
```

`where` is the name of a string column in the model.

But when I'm getting this error:

> undefined method `where_id' for #<ImageDesign:0x007ffaf8aa6400> Did you mean? where

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit obscure but you need to use an array as the value:

`acts_as_list scope: [:where]`

It mentions this in the documentation:

https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list#notes

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, can you accept the answer?